# Data Loss Prevention in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-dlp

Good afternoon guys, a former CISO enabled a DLP discovery on GCP for our entire org. How do I access the result of these discovers since they are not logging into the Security Command Center?

I don't know how to access the data

Answer (score 1):

https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/view-data-profiles

You can access the profiles from the cloud console.